# Issue running Cppcheck with exec() command in PHP

Tags: php, command-line, exec, cppcheck

I am designing a web application which uploads code from server and runs cppcheck on it. I am using PHP for the same.
I tried using `exec($command,$output,$status);` command
and command is `"cppcheck ". $filename;`

The $output array which is returned contains only the first line i.e.:

> Checking file.cpp..

The line

> "(error) Array 'a[10]' accessed at index 10, which is out of bounds."

is displayed in the error.log file of the httpserver. It is actually not a command line error or php error, but an error produced by cppcheck. Is it because the string contains "error" it goes into error.log? How do I fix this?

Comment: Most likely that `cppcheck` command outputs the error message on the stderr stream. You have to redirect it to stdout then. Something like this: `exec('cppcheck somefile 2>&1',$output,$status);`.

Answer (score 0):

As @arkascha pointed out correctly, the output from cppcheck has to be [redirected](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) from the stderr stream to stdout.

According to [the manual, chapter 2.7](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf):

> Many times you will want to save the results in a file. You can use the normal shell redirection for piping
>   error output to a file.
>
> `cppcheck file1.c 2> err.txt`

Your call would then be

```
exec($command.' 2>&1', $output, $status);
```